# Error when installing R package from .tar.gz file

Tags: r

When I have tried to install R package from a .tar.gz file in windows, I have faced with this error:

```
> install.packages("RSQLite-0.11.4.tar.gz", repos=NULL,type="source")

Warning in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
* installing *source* package 'RSQLite' ...

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -DRSQLITE_USE_BUNDLED_SQLITE -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_SOUNDEX -DSQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER=40000 -DSQLITE_MAX_COLUMN=30000    -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c RS-DBI.c -o RS-DBI.o
gcc: unrecognized option `-std=gnu99'
cc1.exe: Invalid option `32'
cc1.exe: Invalid option `tune=core2'
RS-DBI.c: In function `DBI_handle_to_string':
RS-DBI.c:1215: warning: implicit declaration of function `snprintf'
make.exe: *** [RS-DBI.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="RSQLite.dll" OBJECTS="RS-DBI.o RS-SQLite.o param_binding.o sqlite-all.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RSQLite'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.3/library/RSQLite'
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.3\library" "RSQLite-0.11.4.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("RSQLite-0.11.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘RSQLite-0.11.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Could any one help me?

Thanks

Comment: do you have the environment to build from source? do you have a zip of the package instead? there is a newer version on cran, so you can just use `install.packages`

Comment: yes, I have a .tar.gz file of this package, and this command should be executed for local installation of packages from .tar.gz file.

Comment: By upgrading packages, I have installed the newer version of this package, but this version should be installed to resolve my problem about loading "hgu133a.db" package.

Comment: I have converted the .tar.gz file to a .zip file and then install package successfully, Thanks

Comment: I am having the same problem. Could you please tell me how you did convert tar.gz file to a zip file. Thanks.